# JSON in Swift language

Tags: ios, json, swift

I successfully completely a tutorial on displaying the most recent Top Movies from iTunes in a `UITableView` using `Swift`, but now I want to replace the iTunes `JSON` info with my own. Though it works well and displays the iTunes info, my information does not display. I've tried various things with `valueForKeyPath`but still nothing.

**.SWIFT FILE**

```
let urlString = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=25/json"
var titles = [String]()

func fetchItems(success: () -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        var jsonError: NSError?
        let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary

        if let unwrappedError = jsonError{
            println("json error: \(unwrappedError)")
        } else {
            self.titles = json.valueForKeyPath("feed.entry.im:name.label") as [String]
            success()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This works successfully, but when I add the following url instead of iTunes' and try to change the `valueForKeyPath` I run into runtime errors.

**JSON FILE**

```
{"results":[

     {"text":"@twitterapi  http://tinyurl.com/ctrefg",

     "to_user_id":396524,

     "to_user":"TwitterAPI",

     "from_user":"jkoum",

     "metadata":

     {

      "result_type":"popular",

      "recent_retweets": 109



     },

     "id":1478555574,   

     "from_user_id":1833773,

     "iso_language_code":"nl",

     "source":"<a href="http://twitter.com/">twitter< /a>",

     "profile_image_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/118412707/2522215727_a5f07da155_b_normal.jpg",

     "created_at":"Wed, 08 Apr 2009 19:22:10 +0000"},

     ... truncated ...],

     "since_id":0,

     "max_id":1480307926,

     "refresh_url":"?since_id=1480307926&amp;q=%40twitterapi",

     "results_per_page":15,

     "next_page":"?page=2&amp;max_id=1480307926&amp;q=%40twitterapi",

     "completed_in":0.031704,

     "page":1,

     "query":"%40twitterapi"}

}
```

Is this `JSON` file different somehow from that of iTunes? What would I use as `valueForKeyPath`?

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: _UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: that's when I use 'valueForKeyPath("results.text.to_user_id.to_user.from_user")'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.text.to_user_id.to_user.from_user` in your key path is invalid, `text`, `to_user_id` `to_user` and `from_user` are all siblings.

If you want `from_user` your keypath should be `results.from_user`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense when I look back at iTunes' JSON file...but I'm still getting an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error. Am I missing a confused optional somewhere?

Comment: The error falls on this line: "let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary"

Comment: Does `data` contain anything? You should check `error` before attempting to deserialize the `data` object as it could be nil when there is an error.

Comment: There's your problem. `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` means that you tried to access an Optional with a None value. `data` comes back as an implicitly unwrapped optional from the `session.dataTaskWithURL` completion block. Check that it is not nil before using it.

Comment: Great, thanks! But...my confusion is what changed from iTunes' JSON file and mine? Why did data receive the info then and not now? Is it a different type of JSON file? That would mean my code is catered to one type of JSON file and not the other.

Comment: Typically when `data` is `nil`, your request failed. The JSON was never received. Also, the schema between iTunes JSON and what you've posted here are wildly different. So you need to handle them differently. Requesting them will be the same process though. Check that `error` object, it will probably shed some light on what's failing.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file you provided looks fine, but put it through http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure.

Also make sure your valueForKeyPath is correct. I suggest trying to play around with Apple's one to make sure it works first before going on to yours.